# Does T'Pau start the 'Vulcanism' presented in TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise, vulcan, spock

Does T'Pau mark the beginning of that kind of Vulcan culture and self-concept that will later be embodied by Spock?

Her rise to power is accompanied by a clear break in how Vulcans perceive themselves; so does her rediscovery of the original writings of Surak lead to the Spock-kind of Vulcan?

Comment: As the series is a prequel, tos history and events in enterprise do not match up

Comment: But ENT can explain certain things because of its very nature as a prequel - and it does, e.g. the lack of cranial ridges of the Klingons in TOS.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious from these ENT episodes that the answer is "yes" - that was the whole point of them.

Comment: I agree that this is IMPLIED bit it can't be inevitably deduced just by watching the episode(s). That's why I asked.